# Extract public key from private key in C#

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption

I used `sn.exe` to generate a key pair (private and public key). I extract a public key from private key as follows:

`sn -p keyPair.snk publicKey.snk`

I read it by using C# and store it in database as binary to use for encrypting my data.

Is there any way to extract a public key from a private key in C# without using `sn.exe`?

**NOTE** : I want a public key as a `byte` to compare it with the one I store in my database.

Comment: Why are you using public key encryption, and why are you using sn.exe to generate your keys? What is security threat are you trying to protect against?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import an .snk file generated with sn.exe in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095355/how-to-import-an-snk-file-generated-with-sn-exe-in-net)

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any way to extract a public key from a private key in C# without using sn.exe?

It is surprisingly difficult to do that but it is possible; I have done so.

What you need to do is p/invoke to StrongNameGetPublicKey in mscorwks.dll.

> I read it by using C# and store it in database as binary to use for encrypting my data

**This is an extremely bad idea**. The purpose of a strong name public key is not to encrypt your data!  The purpose of a strong name public key is **for your customers to verify that the assembly you gave them was written by you.** If you are using the public key for anything other than that task *you are doing something very, very wrong* and you should stop doing so immediately.

Strong names use encryption, but they are not an encryption technology; they are an *evidence producing* technology for the purpose of *code access security policy evaluation*.

Comment: BY USING SN.EXE  . I CAN GENERATE RSA KEY WITH 1024 – 2048 BIT 
SO WHAT IS THE WRONG IF I USED IT TO ENCRYPT MY DATA ????
I TRIED TO USE PUTTY-GEN BUT  IT DOSEN’T WORK IN C#
MY PROBLEM IS TO MAKE A MULTIBLE ENCYPTION TO ENCRYPT SECURE DATA 
AND DECRYPT DATA AFTER I RESTORE THE PRIVATE KEYS IN MY DATABASE ….
I WANT TO MATCH EACH PRIVATE KEY WITH THE SUITABLE PUBLIC KEY IN MY DATABASE 
SO I NEED TO EXTRACT THE PUBLIC KEY FROM MY PRIVATE KEY ….
ANY SUGGESTION

Comment: Might want to give that "Caps Lock" key on your keyboard a little press.

Comment: @user726072: My suggestion is that you **use the correct tool for the job**. If you intend to generate an RSA key for encryption then why are you messing around with a tool designed to strong-name a file in the first place? Just make an instance of `RSACryptoServiceProvider`! You can then get the exponent and modulus out of the RSAParameters.